# When recv blocks?

Tags: c, linux, epoll

The goal is to read data from a socket without blocking. The Linux manual page says:

> The receive calls normally return any data available, up to the
>   requested amount, rather than waiting for receipt of the full amount
>   requested.

Does it mean that I don't have to pass `MSG_DONTWAIT` flag to `recv()` after polling the socket descriptor with `select()`/`poll()`/`epoll()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The behaviour of `recv`/`read` depends on the characteristics of the socket itself. If the socket is marked as non-blocking, these calls should immediately return `EAGAIN`/`EWOULDBLOCK` rather than blocking the process.

The socket can be marked as non-blocking prior to reading from it, usually via `fcntl` or `ioctl`.

What this excerpt from the manual says is that, basically, reads on both blocking and non-blocking sockets are not required to fill the whole buffer that is supplied. That is why it is important to check the result of the `recv`/`read` calls in order to know how much of the buffer contains the actual data and how much is garbage.

It is not a good idea at all to use blocking sockets in conjunction with the IO polling calls such as `select`/`poll`/`epoll`. Even if the polling call indicates that a particular socket is ready for reading, a blocking socket would sometimes still block.

Comment: I'd also say that what is considered "blocking" also depend on the driver that actually implements `read`, `write` and `poll` calls for a given socket/inode. Sometimes they have their own mysterious point of view on what is blocking and what is not...

Comment: @Blagobest, I am currently encounter a problem that epoll (level-trigger mode) tells me a socket fd is readable whie I got blocked while calling recv() on it. Your answer seems reasonable foe what I've seen. 
May I ask what are the possible reasons that results in spurious wakeups on epoll(), THANKS?

Comment: @kai: I have the same situation and the same question. http://stackoverflow.com/q/41679836/560648

Comment: @Blagovest: _"Even if the polling call indicates that a particular socket is ready for reading, a blocking socket would sometimes still block."_ Can you tell us when that might happen?

Comment: @user405725 It has nothing to do with the driver. The semantics are defined by the Sockets API.