# How could a recv() call block when epoll has signalled activity?

Tags: c++, linux, networking, tcp, epoll

My application is libevent-like, using *epoll* (in level-triggered mode) to detect I/O activity and invoke callbacks to handle it.

I have recently discovered that my TCP/IP sockets are blocking, which was an accident, but still I wouldn't expect a `recv()` call to block on an FD which was reported by `epoll` as having read activity pending. Even if there were an error on the socket, surely `recv()` would return and tell me about it.

What am I misunderstanding about this?
What sort of network condition could lead to `recv()` blocking in such a scenario?

Comment: Did you pass the `MSG_WAITALL` to `recv()`? In this case, the function might block, even though some (but not all) bytes might already be available.

Comment: @RalphTandetzky: No. `recv(fd, buf, BUFSIZE, 0);`

Comment: Usually this happens because epoll+recv is not atomic, so if something else happens between the epoll and the recv, the socket might no longer be ready for reading by the time you call recv. Without an [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), however, its impossible to say what might be happening in your case.

Comment: @ChrisDodd: I'm interested in knowing what sort of "something" that could possibly be. How can a socket be ready one moment, then later not ready with no error condition on it? As for a MCVE, I was never able to reproduce the scenario again :( Hence I'm asking about epoll/recv not about a piece of code.

Comment: It can happen if there are multiple threads reading from the socket.

Comment: @EJP: Okay; anything else? (There aren't.)

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15136338/560648) says _"Even if the polling call indicates that a particular socket is ready for reading, a blocking socket would sometimes still block."_ but doesn't explain why.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the Linux [select](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html) man-page:

> Under Linux, select() may report a socket file descriptor as "ready
>   for reading", while nevertheless a subsequent read blocks.  This
>   could for example happen when data has arrived but upon examination
>   has wrong checksum and is discarded.  There may be other
>   circumstances in which a file descriptor is spuriously reported as
>   ready.  Thus it may be safer to use O_NONBLOCK on sockets that should
>   not block.

(yeah, I know epoll() is not the same as select(), but I suspect the same underlying conditions apply to both)

I think if you really want to avoid blocking, the only safe way to accomplish that is to set your socket to non-blocking mode.

Comment: Aha - this is probably it. Thanks :)

Comment: They should really document this in the manpage the same way it is for ``select``. In fact, the only reason I found this question is because I read the note in ``select``'s manpage and wondered whether the same is true for ``epoll``.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Epoll to poll for EPOLLIN event, then a recv call after that should return immediately. Furthermore, I hope you are making use of non blocking sockets. In case you want to look for errors, then you can look for EPOLLERR events. In case the socket gets closed after epoll signals, then recv should fail. Code snippet of your epoll_wait, epoll_ctl and socket creation will be helpful in debugging the problem.